# How this :$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {\exp^{kx^2}(-x^2)}=\frac{2\Gamma(\frac 5 4)}{k^{\frac 1 4}}$ for $k > 0$?

Tags: integration, closed-form

I have tried many times to play with the positive real $k$ for the below convergent integral over $\mathbb{R}$ to get it's values   , I have got the below [nice identity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(+((+exp(-+kx%C2%B2))%5E(x%C2%B2)),+x%3D-+infty+to+infty) but no way to prove it.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {\exp^{kx^2}(-x^2)}=\frac{2\Gamma(\frac 5 4)}{k^{\frac 1 4}}$$ .

**Then my question here is** : Any simple way to show that ?

Comment: Pleas explain this strange notation: $\exp^{kx^2}(-x^2)$.  Does it mean $\exp(-kx^4)$ ??  And if so, you can surely find that identity on line.

Comment: it mean: (exp(- kx²))^(x²))

Comment: And is that equal to $\exp(-kx^4)$ ??

Comment: $f(x)=e^{kx^2}$ then compute $f(-x^2)$ haven't we not accounted for a sign flip?

Comment: @GEdgar It seems pretty straightforward to me, like $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$: $$\exp^{kx^2}\left(-x^2\right) = \left(e^{\displaystyle\left(-x^2\right)}\right)^{\displaystyle\left(kx^2\right)}$$

Answer (score 2):

The notation is a bit confusing, but I think what you need is

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left[\exp(-x^2) \right]^{k x^2}{\rm d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp(- kx^4) {\rm d}x = 2 \int_{0}^{+\infty} \exp(- kx^4) {\rm d}x
$$

To solve that one call $u = k x^4$, so that ${\rm d}u =  x^{3}{\rm d}x = k [(u/k)^{1/4}]^3{\rm d}x = k u^{3/4} k^{-3/4}{\rm d}x = k^{1/4}u^{3/4}{\rm d}x $, so the integral becomes

$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \exp(- kx^4) {\rm d}x =  k^{-1/4}\int_{0}^{+\infty}u^{-3/4}e^{-u}{\rm d}u
$$

Can you take it from here?